# order_by a hybrid method using flask-sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to implement a search that orders the results by a combination of the number of matching words in the system description, system name, and system tags as well as the number of times that the system has been viewed by other users (system_hits). I'm trying to use a hybrid attribute to do this but something is wrong with my implementation, I keep getting the error **"SQL expression object or string expected, got object of type  instead"**, any insight as to why I'm getting this error?

### app.py

```
@hybrid_method
def relevance(self,searchTag):
    wordsInName = self.system_name.split() #turn string into list of strings
    wordsInDescription = self.system_description.split()
    wordsInTags = self.tags.split()
    nameOccurrences = 0
    descriptionOccurrences = 0
    tagOccurrences = 0
    for word in wordsInName:
        if word == searchTag:
            nameOccurrences += 1
    for word in wordsInDescription:
        if word == searchTag:
            descriptionOccurrences += 1
    for word in wordsInTags:
        if word == searchTag:
            tagOccurrences += 1
    occurrenceRating = (nameOccurrences+descriptionOccurrences*.3+tagOccurrences*2)
    return self.system_hits*occurrenceRating

@relevance.expression(cls,searchTag):
     return self.system_hits

results = System.query.order_by(System.relevance)
```

As you can see, in the expression part I haven't figured out how to right my function yet, I'm just ordering by the number of hits. If you have any advice on how to write the above function using sqlalchemy, that would also help, but this concern is less immediate.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to let Python do the sorting, here is my final implementation:

```
wordsInName = self.system_name.split()
        wordsInDescription = self.system_description.split()
        wordsInTags = [tag.tag_name for tag in self.tags]
        nameOccurrences = 0
        descriptionOccurrences = 0
        tagOccurrences = 0
        for word in wordsInName:
            if word == searchTag:
                nameOccurrences += 1
        for word in wordsInDescription:
            if word == searchTag:
                descriptionOccurrences += 1
        for word in wordsInTags:
            if word == searchTag:
                tagOccurrences += 1
        occurrenceRating = (nameOccurrences+descriptionOccurrences*.3+tagOccurrences*2)
        return self.system_hits*occurrenceRating
```

**Note**: A list comprehension is used to get the tags since there is a many-to-many relationship between Systems and Tags.

```
results = System.query.all()
results.sort(key=lambda x: x.relevance(searchTag),reverse=True)
```